# exsisting database synchronize with laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel

I have designed a database using mysql workbench and synchronize, then my mysql database exists @ phpmyadmin . then how can I use this database with laravel.. I mean I need to create migration files for existing database and continue editing..

Comment: You don't need the migrations. Just import a sql dump of the existing database and use migrations from this point forward. Unless you are planning on working with seeders, then migrations are a must.

Comment: I need to sync my existing database @ phpmyadmin with laravel migration files.... is it possible.. if there a way to import my sql file how can i do that. no one can explain... no one can understand even no explanations at laravel documentation.

Comment: Explain me why can't you import the exported sql file from phpmyadmin to Laravel?

Comment: Think.. I dont have any migration schema with my project `database->migrations` but I have a database running @ `localhost->phpmyadmin` then I need to generate migration schema according that database tables.. Example:- I have a table called `new_table` and it has two fields `id` and `name` after that I created a migration file using `php artisan make:migration new_table`

Comment: CONTINUE.....   then I have a `database->migrations->2016_01_28_045837_new_table` but the schema is empty how can I get my database table fields into this migration file... is it possible..

Answer (score 2):

You should write the migration files, so your schema can be built from zero without a manual intervention. But if you can't or you don't want to do it, you can start your migrations from your desired point:

```
php artisan make:migration blablabla
```

Write the new schema and:

```
php artisan migrate
```

And so on.

Comment: without doing each and every migration codes one by one... is it possible to sync my existing database tables into migration files......

Answer (score 0):

You could you this package
[Migrations Generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator)

1. Include it in your project(via composer or directly downloading it    into your vendor folder) and configure service providers.
2. run: `php artisan migrate:generate` to generate the migrations for all the tables in you current database. To generate the migrations for specific tables, run `php artisan migrate:generate table1,table2,table3,table4,table5`.

Answer (score 0):

while in developing stage you can use : https://github.com/awssat/laravel-sync-migration

by using :

```
php artisan migrate:sync
```

but I won't recommend use it for production since you can't track the migrations changes

Answer (score 0):

My situation was the following:

- I had hundreds of migration classes in the database/migrations folder.
- My classes had already been migrated, but at some point I imported an old 
  version of my migration table by accident.
- My migrations table had fewer records than my classes.

After trying everything, I decided to walk the extra mile and solve my problem like this:

I created a method in a temporary controller. Basically, it checks through all my migration classes in database/migrations folder and then checks if they exist in the migrations table. If not, insert them into the table. Called the method from the browser and now everything is synched

```
 public function syncMigration(){
        $migrations_folder = database_path('migrations');
        $filesInFolder = File::files($migrations_folder);
        $lastMigration = DB::table('migrations')->orderBy('batch', 'desc')->limit(1)->first();
        var_dump($lastMigration);

        $batch = $lastMigration->batch +1;


        foreach($filesInFolder as $path) {
            $file = pathinfo($path);
            $migration = DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', $file['filename'])->first();
            if(!$migration){
                DB::table('migrations')->insert(
                    [
                        'migration' => $file['filename'],
                        'batch' => $batch
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }
```